# What the difference between send_request_date and sent_date in sysmail_mailitems in sql server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, gmail

I have an sql jobs that send out notifications using gmail and noticed that the timestamp on the received date of an email in gmail, itself, is closer to the send_request_date field for that email in sql server rather than the actual sent_date field(25 minutes and in some cases 1 hour later).can anyone explain why?

Answer (score 1):

`send_request_date` refers to when the email was placed on queue

`sent_date` is when the email was actually sent

That means it's likely an issue with the email server, which is causing your messages to be delivered with a certain delay.

I'm not entirely sure as I haven't done any testing on this part, but I'm assuming that as your email is placed on queue, its 'sent date' value will be the time of when it was placed on queue, instead of when it was actually sent. Somebody please correct me on this one.

This page has a link which lets you troubleshoot email issues: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/537d86d6-b878-4f00-ba5c-29c66f7d5b15/database-mail-sentdate-5-hours-after-sendrequestdate?forum=sqldatabaseengine